# Import Cucumber Scenarios

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I have multiple maven projects that use the same Cucumber Scenarios, what I want to do know is if there is any possibility to share those Scenarios between all the projects through parent pom files or any other solution.

What I'm trying to avoid is the easy solution than consists of duplicating all the scenarios in all the projects.

I'm using the following dependencies :

`junit`

`info.cukes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a jar that includes all of your Cucumber Scenarios and make it a dependency for your project. That way you have one place where you can manage, refactor, and maintain all of your shared tests.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing